# Thevenin theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

Hi i got the trouble and i miss the concept about v out in thevenin 
i have the circuit like this 
[image]

so i used voltage divider for finding the voltage at point 1,
 but how to finding voltage at Vo , is that same the result of voltage at 2 , and voltage between R2 and R3 , 
i thought at R2 and R3 we need voltage divider calculation also , from voltage at point 2, is that true? . if The calculation like that there is a voltage difference between two Vout

Comment: Perhaps [Electrical Engineering SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/) would be more suited for this question.

Comment: @Physicist137 Maybe. Although don't freshman physicists study this kind of thing as well?

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance (what a large name to write).... They do. That's why I guess this question was not closed as off topic here. On this case, I was merely pointing out that on EE SE has a far greater chance of this question being answered, than here.

Comment: @Physicist137 Then I'll answer: I don't like the way some EEs deal with Thévenin and Norton methods, which assign poncy names to very simple, widely applicable principles of linearity and can thus rob the student of a more unified view of the World.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance haha... well... I agree with you. I don't like it either. By the way, your answer is nice. =).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though you're on the right track: if I understand correctly, you're saying that once you have found the voltage across the pair $R_1 and R_4$ (equal to the voltage across $R_2$ and $R_3$), presumably by lumping $R_1,\,R_2\,R_3\,R_4$ together through parallel addition of $R_1 +R_4$ and $R_2+R_3$, then you simply work out $V_o$ thinking of $R_2,\,R_3$ as a voltage divider. This is indeed correct.

However I am a little puzzled by your mention of Thévenin if the above is your approach. Presumably your question asks for you to use Thévenin's theorem, which is simply a big name for the statement that the output current to voltage relationship is linear, and you can fully define such a relationship by drawing a straight line between two points, which happen in Thévenin's "theorem" to be the voltage at zero current (open circuit) and current at zero voltage (dead short).

So, take out $R_1$ and calculate the voltage across the gap: this is simply the voltage across $R_1$ and $R_4$ with $R_2$ and $R_3$ removed. This is your open circuit voltage $V_T$. Now consider a dead short in place of $R_2$ and calculate the current $I_T$ through $R_3$ in this configuration. By linearity, the circuit is equivalent to $V_T$ driving $R_2$ through the Thévenin resistance $V_T/I_T$. Now you apply the voltage divider notion  to the ladder $R_2$ and $R_T$ to find $V_o=E_1\,R_2/(R_T+R_2)$.

In this special case, there is an easy approach by symmetry. By the mirror symmetry, the circuit is equivalent to $E_1/2=6V$ driving $R_5$ in series with $R_1$ paralleled with $R_2$. This means that the $R_1$ paralled with $R_2$ (with half the resistance of $R_5$) is going to feel a third of the source's voltage across it, namely $2V$.

Comment: I strongly disagree with your statement that "[...]Thévenin's theorem, which is simply a big name for the statement that the output current to voltage relationship is linear". As an analogy, you could similarly say that  electron interference is "simply" a consequence of the linearity of Schroedinger's equation. Norton and Thevenin are at the heart of almost any antenna, power amplifier, LNA, mixer, etc., design activity, it is definitely not "just" linearity!

Comment: @hyportnex What I am saying is that, although Thévenin's work was a big step for the late nineteenth century, it belongs in a more unified framework, and that framework is the notion of linearity. And indeed interference is a consequence of linearity; that doesn't make it any less mysterious: indeed I still find the notion that QM is, as far as we can test, utterly linear (*i.e.* that states live in linear spaces) to be one of the most mind blowing things in all of science. Mostly one finds linearity to be an approximation to higher order behavior: QM seems fundamentally different in this way.

Comment: to make the point that Thevenin's (or Norton's) theorem is a lot more complicated and subtle concept than just invoking "linearity" I urge you to read the article by Collin "Limitations of the Thevenin and Norton Equivalent Circuits for a Receiving Antenna" and the referenced papers therein, and also the one that spawned the controversy by Love:"EQUIVALENT CIRCUIT FOR APERTURE ANTENNAS". The apparent simplicity is quite misleading.